# java returns VM error after upgrade in centos 6.5

Tags: java, linux, centos

I want to upgrade my jdk on a centos server, after some simple searches i found some solutions.

from this link you can see that the instructions are simple:
[jdk 7 installation guide for centos](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

-install your jdk from rpm package or from source

-do some alternatives

-check the practical version (java -version)

and i go easy with the first two steps but in check version step i get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

i have also checked `alternatives --config java` and simbolic links.

i have also tried `which` command to find out what java is actually running and this was the link directoins.

`/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/java/jdk-1.8.0_40/bin/java`

the weird point is when i run `/usr/bin/java -version` it is OK and it returns the version but when i run `java` without any prefix i got that error.

so what is the problem?

Comment: report the results of rpm --verify java-<installed_version>

Comment: It says "package java is not installed" but i have it under /usr/java/jdk1.8.0 and when i give the full path it works. Or maybe i'm wrong in format. Are you sure about java-1.8.0_40 in place of version? I think when you install a package from source rpm does not have information.

Comment: you have to use the name of the package you installed (`rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/java/jdk1.8.0` if you don't remember)

Comment: file /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40 is not owned by any package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to setup CLASSPATH variable so that jvm could load needed libraries.

see this post https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: According to oracle docs "The CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the JDK tools, where to look for user classes" and i think java -version does not need it. In addition i don't know what path should be the CLASSPATH. Could you please explain more. My installation directory is in /usr/java/jdk1.8.0/

Comment: CLASSPATH is an environment/system variable, java uses this variable to look for the classes to run a particular java program. There are some basic jdk jars that exists under /usr/java/jdk1.8.0/lib directory. Those jars path must be setup so that jdk can load them while executing and java program. In your case CLASSPATH = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0/lib has to be setup.

Comment: setting up CLASSPATH, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

Comment: You were right CLASSPATH was exactly the cause of error.